# Running robot_pose_ekf and amcl

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to use the [Leg Detector](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) package on the Turtlebot to detect people and then send goals to the navigation stack to follow a person. Separately, running leg detection and amcl work fine. However, when you run them together there are problems. robot_pose_ekf, which the leg_detector needs, seems to interfere with amcl somehow. Can anyone explain why this happens and how I can get around it? I think it's problem some duplication in pose estimation, so maybe hopefully it's something easy that I'm missing.

Thanks,
Sarah

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203953/running-robot_pose_ekf-and-amcl/) by [velveteenrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6196/velveteenrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2015-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One possibility is that there are interfering published transforms. Did you try dumping the tf graph both with and without `amcl` running? E.g., `rosrun tf view_frames`. To debug this, you could try spawning the `amcl` with modified `odom_frame_id`, `base_frame_id`, and `global_frame_id` parameters. Confer http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Parameters (near the bottom of the page).

You wrote that `robot_pose_ekf` is required by `leg_detector`. However, there is no indication of this in the package description. It is required to specify a reference frame (parameter `fixed_frame`), which could be provided by multiple packages, e.g., `robot_pose_ekf` or `amcl`.

---

Originally posted by [slivingston](https://answers.ros.org/users/829/slivingston/) with karma: 254 on 2015-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0